# Copy of environments/development asset path cannot find jquery-ui-rails in gems directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I copied config/environments/development.rb to config/environments/ci.rb.

When I run with RAILS_ENV=development, the asset search path includes my gem vendor directories, in particular for jquery-ui-rails.  However, when I run with RAILS_ENV=ci it does not.

From the console, Rails.application.config.assets.paths evaluates to the following with development

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/images",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/javascripts",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/stylesheets",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
  "/opt/comcast/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts",
  "/opt/comcast/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-1.0.0/vendor/assets/images",
  "/opt/comcast/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-1.0.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
  "/opt/comcast/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-ui-rails-1.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"]
```

but for ci I only get the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.application.config.assets.paths
=> ["/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/images",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/javascripts",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/app/assets/stylesheets",
  "/var/www/ci/conflux/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
  "/opt/comcast/ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-1.0.19/vendor/assets/javascripts"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you added the ci environment into `config/application.rb`?

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test ci)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @mccannf has the right answer but if it isn't the problem, have you added the jquery-ui-rails gem to the the `ci` group into `Gemfile`?

Comment: jquery-ui-rails was in the assets group, where Rails new put it.  Yes, sometimes you can bundle --without development test assets, and then later wonder where your development gems are, but that's the case here.  Thanks.