# Integrate rake-pipeline with Rails asset paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, asset-pipeline

Is there a good way to integrate rake-pipeline with the Rails asset paths?

Specifically, I'm trying to bundle JS files from a gem with my files in app/assets.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963106/copy-of-environments-development-asset-path-cannot-find-jquery-ui-rails-in-gems

Answer (score 1):

You can customize precompiled assets sources in the environment configuration — e.g, *(by default)* in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```ruby
App::Application.configure do
  #...

  config.assets.precompile += %w( ember.js your_additional_gem_asset.js )

  #...
end
```

*Your additional gem asset reference may include relative `assets` directory path.*